# Android: Recource$NotFoundException

Tags: android, exception

Im working with android, and am releatively new to it, Ive got an exception I cant seem to fix.

Logcat output

```
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.metronome/com.metronome.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x78
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x78
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3432)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at com.metronome.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
10-24 13:50:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(772):  ... 11 more
```

Ive read that people say to fix the problem by cleaning the project but I have tried that twice and it didnt help. I also creted another project and copied the code, so I think it is something different. Any help is appreciated.

Line 36

```
txtBPM1.setText(120, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Comment: What is the code at your `MainActivity.java` line 36?

Comment: Post the line where you're accessing the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change 120 to be a string like so :

```
txtBPM1.setText(""+120, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Comment: I know this is weird,  but sometimes when i leave my computer on for too long (sleep/hibernate/etc) this has worked for me.

Comment: I changed my answer since you posted line 36

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you access some controls or which is not present in your layout you pass on `onCreate` in you activity `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);`. Just checkout all the id's , string's and other controls which you are using belongs to same layout or not

Comment: Well ive gone over it again and it looks like all of the ids are named properly, no inconsistancies. I just have the one class and .xml so thats not a problem either. Sould I post the code to get another set of eyes on it, maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

(your error in MainActivity.java:line 36 (it is import generated R))
1.delete error line from import and use pop-up message on red R.id.****
2. close and reopen IDE